# Flash Of Unstyled Text (FOUT) on reload using next.js and styled components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, styled-components, vercel

I'm using global style from styled components with next.js and every time I reload my page I can see the font flickering.

[image: font flash]

I have my font files in `public/fonts/Inconsolata`

I've looked everywhere in spectrum chat, next.js github issues but can't seem to find any solution.

**pages/index.js**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const H1 = styled.h1`
  font-family: 'Inconsolata Bold';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
`;

const index = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <H1>font flashes</H1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default index;
```

**pages/_app.js**

```
import App from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';

import GlobalStyle from '../src/style/globalStyle';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**pages/_document.js**

```
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        )
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

**style/globalStyle.js**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

const globalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata';
    src:  url('./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: fallback;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata Bold';
    src:  url('./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: bold;
    font-display: fallback;
  }
`;

export default globalStyle;
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: You could resolved it?

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE:

Next.js released a new feature called **[Automatic Webfont Optimization](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10-2#automatic-webfont-optimization)**.

Just include your font (it works only with Google Fonts so far) and it will be included as raw css on build-time.

```
// Before
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

// After
<style data-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter">
  @font-face{font-family:'Inter';font-style:normal.....
</style>
```

---

Check out how Next.js guys handle it on their website, which is open-source and can be found [here](https://github.com/vercel/next-site). Check it out, it worked for me.

1. Import your used font in css @font-face via preload link

   ```
   <link
       rel="preload"
       href="/assets/my-font.woff2"
       as="font"
       type="font/woff2"
   />
   ```
2. Your font declaration should be on SSR HTML page, so use `<style jsx global />` to include it in your page. It can be an external file or right directly in `style` element.

Comment: nextjs website is not available anymore, at least I can't find it

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with NextJS 12, Google Fonts and SCSS modules.

My partial solution was to

1. 'preload' the resources being requested in any `@font-face` rules in any CSS file - load the fonts more eagerly
2. set `font-display: optional` - tell CSS to use fallback if font not loaded in time

This means no Flash Of Unstyled Text (FOUT) but on slower connections a fallback font will be used on first load instead.

```
   <head>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
      <link
        rel="preload"
        href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inconsolata/v21/QlddNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKENVzkWGVkL3GZQmAwLyya15IDhunA.woff2"
        as="font"
        type="font/woff2"
        crossOrigin=""
      />
      <link
        rel="preload"
        href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inconsolata/v21/QlddNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKENVzkWGVkL3GZQmAwLyx615IDhunJ_o.woff2"
        as="font"
        type="font/woff2"
        crossOrigin=""
      />
       // CSS file with @font-face rules and font-display: optional
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300;400;700&display=optional"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
</head>
```

In this example, the last `link` element requests a CSS file which has a number of `@font-face` rules with `src` declarations and `url()` values.

If the resources in the `url()` functions aren't preloaded in the head then they wont be requested until the CSS is parsed.

I think this is what causes the FOUT.

By including `<link rel="preload" src="..."/>` elements fonts can be loaded sooner.

And [setting `font-display: optional`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display) tells the browser that if the font hasn't loaded in time to use a fallback.

The site I was working on: [Soundboard](https://next-family-soundboard.vercel.app/mamma)

Comment: Thank you! This was the _only_ setup that worked for me after lots of searching!

Comment: As you can see, the problem with that approach is that the font's version changes. As you can see in the file: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300;400;700&display=optional 

The "preload" link is pointing at  v21 and the file is already at v31.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `style.css` file in your `public/fonts/` directory. Copy and paste your `@font-face` part in `style.css`.

#### style.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Inconsolata";
  src: url("./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: fallback;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Inconsolata Bold";
  src: url("./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./fonts/Inconsolata/Inconsolata-Bold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: bold;
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

In your `pages/_app.js` import the `style.css` file in head.

#### _app.js

```
import App from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';
import Head from "next/head";

import GlobalStyle from '../src/style/globalStyle';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/style.css" />
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hat tip to [Raul Sanchez on dev.to for the answer to this one](https://dev.to/rsanchezp/next-js-and-styled-components-style-loading-issue-3i68):

Next doesn't fetch `styled-components` styles on the server, to do that you need to add this page to `pages/_document.js`:

```js
import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
}
```

This code may update, so check [Next's `styled-components` example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/main/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js) for the latest.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and after hours of experimenting with different methods npm package `fontfaceobserver` solved the problem for me.

With the package you can tell your app to render only after fonts are loaded, thus avoiding FOUT like so:

```
import FontFaceObserver from "fontfaceobserver";

const font = new FontFaceObserver("Inconsolata");

font.load().then(()=> {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

Comment: I don't think you really want to have your whole app be waiting to render based on the font. Also, this wouldn't work for SPA, and it's odd to do for SSR.